# Batch File Move depending on file name

Tags: sorting, batch-file

I have collection of 35k lyrics in .txt files. They are all in one folder.
Is there a way to sort them all in separate Folders (by Artist name for example)

Here is a screenshot, how it looks.

http://my.jetscreenshot.com/201/20121128-mrwo-76kb

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you give it ago yet? You're more likely to get good help if you have a go at it and then ask questions about if/where you're stuck. Just asking someone to do it all for you (for free) isn't likely to win you many favours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that without errors, how do you think the system knows what is a artist or a title name when you split the filename?

For example  **A-HA - My song**  There are 3 **-** then "**A**" becomes the artist and **HA- My song** becomes the song title.

So is not possible with 100% accuracy, you need to make manual repairs.

PS: Sorry for my english.

try this:

```
@Echo OFF

:: By Elektro H@cker


FOR %%@ IN (*) DO (
    Set "Filename=%%@"
    Call :Split "%FILENAME%"
    CMD /C "If not "%%Last_artist%%" EQU "%%artist_name%%" (ECHO Processing: "%%artist_name%%")"
    Call MKDIR "%%artist_name%%" 2>NUL
    Call COPY /Y "%%artist_name%%*" "%%artist_name%%\" >NUL
    Call Set "Last_artist=%%artist_name%%"
)
Pause&exit


:SPLIT
SET "title_name=%FILENAME:*-=%"
CALL SET "artist_name=%%Filename:%title_name%=%%"
CALL SET "artist_name=%%artist_name:~0,-1%%"
IF "%artist_name:~-1%" EQU " " (CALL SET "artist_name=%%artist_name:~0,-1%%")
GOTO:EOF
```

Example output:

```
Processing: "Flyleaf"
Processing: "Flyleaf Vs. The Legion Of Doom"
Processing: "Folk Implosion"
Processing: "Foo Fighters"
Processing: "For All Those Sleeping"
Processing: "Foster The People"
Processing: "Four Year Strong"
Processing: "Franco & Oscarcito"
Processing: "From First To Last"
Processing: "Fuel"
Processing: "Full Blown Rose"
Processing: "Funeral For A Friend"
Processing: "Further Seems Forever"
Processing: "Garbage"
Processing: "Gemini"
Processing: "Georgina"
Processing: "Get Scared"
```

Comment: Thank you Elektro Hacker

I will try that asap,.. trying to import all those txt in sqlite,..

Comment: Its still processing, but looks like its going to work !!!

All artist/folder with letter A and B were created and files moved!!!

Ill keep you posted (wonder how to send you PM or email?)

Thank you soooo much!!!